# Convert string{} to List<int> - C#

Tags: c#

I have a string{} of value `"[1, 2, 3, 4]"`. I would like to convert it to a List.
This is what I have tried:

```
char[] delimiterChars = { '[', ',', ']' };

string text = "[1, 2, 3, 4]";
text = text.Replace("[", "");
text = text.Replace("]", "");
List<int> numbers = new List<int>( Array.ConvertAll(text.Split(delimiterChars ), int.Parse) );


System.Console.WriteLine($"{numbers}");
```

I get an error:

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
> by the target of an invocation. ---> System.FormatException: Input
> string was not in a correct format.

My expected output is `[1, 2, 3, 4]`.

Please advice.

Comment: Hint: what's the first element of the result of `text.Split(',')`?

Comment: have you tried inspecting the result of splitting your string by commas?  (hint:  the brackets are not removed)

Comment: [1 ?????????????

Comment: It's the [ and ] characters. Strip them out before parsing.

Comment: @a2441918 `[1 ?????????????` ...why is that surprising? Your string split operation just splits on the commas. It doesn't do anything about removing the brackets from the string. You'll find the last item in the array is `4]` as well. And of course neither of those is an integer, so hence you get an error about format when you try to convert them to integer (implicitly, by attempting to add them to a list of integers).

Comment: @ADyson asawyer Updated the OP. Now I get System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32] in the console

Comment: That's because you're trying to print a list. .NET doesn't know how exactly you want to present the list, so it just tells you the type of object instead. To get the output you've requested, you'd have to serialise it to JSON. or you could use a loop to print the values one by one. But then...the data was JSON to begin with, so you don't need such a verbose parsing routine in the first place. Just deserialise it from JSON into a list of ints. Your expected output is identical to the expected input, visually.

Comment: You edited your question with the fix, so it should no longer produce the error, but your question still states that it does. A better option might have been to accept one of the answers.

Comment: *Why* are you defining a string with brackets only to remove them as a first step in processing it?  I smell an XY

Comment: Its coming from an Excel file being parsed.

Comment: Code shown in the post does not produce error that is claimed to happen by running the code. It is very unclear what exact problem is as code does indeed converts string to list of integers (clearly parsing JSON as JSON would be better, but code show is doing that special case parsing ok). Please review [MCVE] guidance on posting code and [edit] question to make sure data, code,  and output/error match each other demonstrating what you trying to achieve at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to strip the brackets [] out before formatting.

```
string text = "[1, 2, 3, 4]";
string fixedText = text.Trim('[', ']');
List<int> numbers = new List<int>( Array.ConvertAll(fixedText.Split(','), int.Parse) );
```

Comment: Code in the post does indeed strips brackets already (not really optimal way, but ok). Suggesting something better (like JSON parsing) would be an answer, not sure how this is applicable.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov they edited the question after I had submitted my answer.

Answer (score 6):

Looks json-like to me...

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

string text = "[1, 2, 3, 4]";
List<int> numbers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<int>>(text);
```

Though to be honest, you are using a string constant... so....

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>() {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

would work just as well.

Comment: Yes also doubting if this is a XY problem

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

...

List<int> numbers = text
    .TrimStart('[') 
    .TrimEnd(']') 
    .Split(',')
    .Select(int.Parse) // items to int
    .ToList();
```

[demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OAnvnC)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quickly fixed version of your sample:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // char[] delimiterChars = { '[', ',', ']' }; // <- NO NEED OF THIS

        string text = "[1, 2, 3, 4]";
        text = text.Replace("[", "");
        text = text.Replace("]", "");
        // List<int> numbers = new List<int>( Array.ConvertAll(text.Split(delimiterChars ), int.Parse) ); // <- You just have to split your string with ','
        List<int> numbers = text.Split(',').Select(item => int.Parse(item)).ToList();

        // Joining back, but not sure why. Actually you could just print the original "text" instead
        System.Console.WriteLine("[" + string.Join(",", numbers) + "]");
    }
}
```